# How to save checkbox options into a database?

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc, checkbox

I have multiple checkboxes on a web page. That is, I have 4 different categories of checkboxes. For example, I have those categories:

1. decoration
2. entertainment
3. catering
4. security.

Each of these have about 5 or more checkboxes.

How do I proceed to save them into a DB? I am using MySQL and JDBC.

Comment: Thanks for the accept. I remember learning about database design a couple of years ago, and when I finally wrapped my head around an online shopping cart, and how the shopping cart has it's own `id`, `timestamp`, `created_by`, and so on attributes, as well as the *contents* of that shopping cart (which comprise the details). Hopefully you stick with a database centric education, it will pay in spades as you move into programming.

Comment: Thanks for the advice droogans. I am working on my final year project, sure it will help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say make them attributes of whatever your form is representing in the database.

In plain English: make them `BOOL` values, in the same table that you're saving to when the user presses the "Submit" button (or whatever you're giving them in the servlet).

## UPDATE

Okay, so if your users can only be one of each:

```
user_types
==========
ut_id        int pk auto_incr
ut_code      varchar(4)
ut_desc      varchar(127)

user_type_details
=================
ut_det_id    int pk auto_incr
ut_id        int fk references user_types
ut_det_code  varchar(4)
ut_det_desc  varchar(127)
```

Your entries would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user_types;

ut_id    ut_code    ut_desc
=====    =======    =======
1        DECO       decoration
2        ENTR       entertainment
3        CATR       catering
4        SECR       security


SELECT * FROM user_type_details WHERE ut_id = 2;

ut_det_id   ut_id    ut_det_code   ut_det_desc
=========   =====    ===========   ===========
7           2        D.J.          dj
8           2        SNGR          singer
9           2        DNCR          dancer
10          2        GTRS          guitarist
```

And so on.

Comment: something like - for entertainment i have dj, live band, singer, dancer..
i should save all these to the db and use either true /false?

Comment: Okay, you have *nested* checkboxes: I can have attributes of the `entertainment` options, as well as say...`vendor`, `management`, etc.? Or can you be only one type? It will change my answer.

Comment: yes something like
i have 4 category of checkboxes: 
1. entertainment- dj, magician, live band, singer
2. decoration - florist, hand made crafts, vases, glasses, lightings
3. security- parking, security guards
4.catering- buffet, dessert, lunch

Comment: If that's the case, then you'll want to normalize that sort of structure. Ill update my answer.